# DRF - creating multiple endpoints for PATCH request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to create multiple endpoints for PATCH request.

For eg.

```
class CityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows city to be viewed or edited.
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ()
    queryset = City.objects.filter(active=True)
    serializer_class = CitySerializer

class CitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'is_metro', 'is_village', 'active')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if not isinstance(value, (list,dict)):
                setattr(instance, attr, value)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'city', CityViewSet)
```

Can I create multiple routers which finally go to PATCH request of this viewset only? In the update method, based on the url, I will decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can register different url's for the same viewset, like:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'city', CityViewSet)
router.register(r'town', CityViewSet.as_view({'patch':'partial_update'})
```

If you're using a browsable API and DRF is creating reverse urls, you will probably get the first ones there (in the example above - with 'city')

If you want only PATCH with the second link, then doing .as_view({'patch':'partial_update'}) will prevent from reaching it with other methods, as it will throw MethodNotAllowed if you will try to reach it with any other method.

Comment: I can add a base_name there so that both of them can be there. But If I do that all the methods will be there and I only want Patch method. Also, I would like to get the prefix/base_name in update method of Viewset.

Comment: you can do then like this:

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'city', CityViewSet)
router.register(r'town', CityViewSet.as_view({'patch':'partial_update'})). I'll update the answer

Comment: How can I access the URL in my view?

Comment: You want to check, from which url it got there in a partial update? I'm not sure how you can do this, but maybe you should check `request` parameter, maybe there is a url parameter (I don't have access to it now).

You can also write two different views for the same serializer.

Comment: by the way, PATCH matches update_partial, not update, update is for PUT. and you should overwrite a view's update_partial method, not serializers, I think.